# How to track keyup and keydown in electron app?

Tags: electron

Used globalShortcut to track the click, however, it's not really a solution that works for me.
I need to be able to track at least keydown keys

How to do this?

Used globalShortcut to track the click, however, it's not really a solution that works for me.
How to do this?